# Изменение положения блоков в верстке при изменении размеров окна браузера

Tags: jquery, вёрстка, css

Верстка имеет такой вид https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUBeY.jpg
При сужении окна блоки должна сдвигаться таким образом https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxvkR.jpg
И при совсем узком окне блоки должны располагаться так https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RQEz.jpg
Не совсем представляю, можно ли этого вообще добиться, и если можно, то как.
Пока при изменении размеров окна браузера скриптом убирается-добавляется свойство float у некоторых блоков

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).resize(function () {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
   if (windowWidth < 1150) {
        $(".two_blocks").css("float", "none");

        if (windowWidth < 830) {
            $(".item").css("float", "none");}

        else {
            $(".item").css("float", "left");}

        }
    else {
        $(".two_blocks").css("float", "left");}
});
});
```

За счет этого при некотором сужении окна получилось добиться такого вида https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYgmg.jpg, но это не совсем то, что нужно.
Верстка выложена [здесь](http://web-portfolio1.narod.ru/index10/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А Вы не слышали про css media queries и адаптивную верстку? Если нет, то советую заняться изучением этой темы, а не городить велосипед из скриптов.

Comment: аа, вот оно как делается! понятно, спасибо, уже читаю.